# Printing split data in function

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to test to see if my function is working properly but every time I run it, it returns nothing. Here is my code:

```
def read_words(user_words):

    user_input_of_words = 'DOG CAT BIRD FISH'   
    words = user_input_of_words.split()

    print read_words(user_input_of_words)
    return words
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You call this function within itself, ie recursively, with no base case, this will never print anything. Did you mean to put this? : print words

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
def read_words(user_words):

    words = user_words.split()
    print (words)
    return

read_words ("DOG CAT")
```